# mustache.js is not working

Tags: javascript, mustache

I am trying to learn mustache js but the basic page does not work. 
I was following the http://iviewsource.com/codingtutorials/introduction-to-javascript-templating-with-mustache-js/ but it is out of the date.
(Currently the basic html doesn't work. In the future I would like to use get JSON in script to get data from json files.)
Am I missing anything?

```html
<!DOCTYPE <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>messages</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/0.8.1/mustache.min.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="loadUser()">
        <div id="target">Loading...</div>
        <script id="template" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
        Hello {{ subject }}!
        </script>
        <script>
            function loadUser() {
                var template = $('#template').html();
                Mustache.parse(template);   // optional, speeds up future uses
                var rendered = Mustache.render(template, {subject: "Luke"});
                $('#target').html(rendered);
            }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax error. Remove extra brackets at the bottom (commented out in the code below).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>messages</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/0.8.1/mustache.min.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="loadUser()">
        <div id="target">Loading...</div>
        <script id="template" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
        Hello {{ subject }}!
        </script>
        <script>
            function loadUser() {
                var template = $('#template').html();
                Mustache.parse(template);   // optional, speeds up future uses
                var rendered = Mustache.render(template, {subject: "Luke"});
                $('#target').html(rendered);
            }
            // }); <-- here
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```